# Refresh Filter Data Extension

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have create one Filter Data Extension using Standard Data Extension. Now, I want to automatically refresh the filter data extension. For that I have to use script activity in Automation studio. So, can you please help me in that?

i have search on it and also use server site script in automation studio but, the filter data extension is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using Filter Activity in Automation Studio for the same purpose:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_a_filter_activity.htm&type=5